# NSRegularExpression class in Xamarin

Tags: ios, regex, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsregularexpression

Can any one suggest me how to use NSRegularExpression class in Xamarin iOS.
I am not able to use this in Xamarin Studio, 
Looking for an equivalent method for the below one

```
   NSArray* matches = [[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:nil] matchesInString:string options:0 range:range];
```

Comment: Maybe [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches` resource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches/p/System.String/) can help? `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` is the same as an inline option `(?s)` that you can add to the beginning of your pattern, or use a `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag with `Regex.Matches`.

Comment: Regex.Matches, Exactly what is expected. Thanks

Comment: Great, I posted an answer then.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Regex.Matches(String,String,RegexOptions)`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches/p/System.String/System.String/System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions/)

> Searches the specified input string for all occurrences of a specified regular expression, using the specified matching options.

`NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators` is the same as an inline option `(?s)` that you can add to the beginning of your pattern, or use a `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag with `Regex.Matches`.